# How to obtain information about contours from ggplot2::geom_density_2d_filled?

Tags: r, ggplot2, heatmap

I can plot heatmap with ggplot2. For example

```
library(tidyverse)

gg <- ggplot(mtcars) + geom_density_2d_filled(aes(x = mpg, y = disp)) +
   theme(legend.position = "none")
```

Is it possible to get information about heatmap contours from `ggplot` object? I need `x`,
`y` and `z` like in `MASS::kde2d` output or another form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This blog post seems to have the answer - https://www.javaer101.com/en/article/42324657.html

```
gdata <- layer_data(gg)    ##  Update - more precise method
#ggbld <- ggplot_build(gg)
#gdata <- ggbld$data[[1]]
head(gdata)
```

Then you can plot by level to demonstrate:

```
gdata %>% ggplot() +geom_point(aes(x, y, color = level))
```

[image]